# Ошибка открытия всплывающего окна с html5lightbox в wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Пытаюсь вызвать форму в всплывающем окне по ссылке в wordpress используя примерно такой код:

```
<a href="#myDiv" class="html5lightbox" data-width=350 data-height=320>тут ссылка вызывающая окно</a>
```

Код формы:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
  <form>
     Тут сама форма
  </form>
</div>
```

Все скрипты подключены. При нажатии на на ссылку открывается не форма, а уменьшенное окно страницы (со всем содержимым) с которой вызывается окно.

Как вызвать только форму, облаченную в `Div`?

Инструкцию по скрипту читал на оффсайте: [инструкция по html5lightbox](https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/)

Может что-то пропустил?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ваша проблема в синтаксической ошибке? У вас написано

```
<div="myDiv"... пропущено id.
```

Мало информации, для проверки.
Как фронтенд разработчик я бы не советовал вам использовать подобные плагины. Платное модальное окно для сайта - звучит ужасно. Посмотрите в сторону простых бесплатных и с полной документаций решений, типа http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: html5lightbox - абсолютно бесплатный скрипт! В выше написанном коде просто поторопился (уже поправил). Учитывая то, что вы подумали, окно вообще бы не срабатывало, а оно открывается, но не с тем, с чем требуется.